# How to compare files in CMake

Tags: cmake

Is there a way to compare files using cmake?
I've checked all parameters from https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/file.html

Comment: Can you post what you have already tried and any related errors?

Comment: I haven't tried anything because I didn't find any cmake instructions for comparing files

Comment: Can you explain what you are actually trying to achieve? Why do you want to compare files?

Answer (score 20):

`cmake` executable has a [tool mode](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake.1.html#command-line-tool-mode), when it performs some useful actions instead of project's configuration. And `compare_files` is one of the commands for that mode.

For get features of the CMake command line tool mode in the `CMakeLists.txt`, use `execute_process` command:

```
execute_process( COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E compare_files <file1> <file2>
                 RESULT_VARIABLE compare_result
)
if( compare_result EQUAL 0)
    message("The files are identical.")
elseif( compare_result EQUAL 1)
    message("The files are different.")
else()
    message("Error while comparing the files.")
endif()
```